# Problems with Visitor 3.01 and The update form tag

Tags: forms, update, visitor

On a simple page with no embeds, the registration tag works well and the form is displayed on the webpage:

```
  {exp:visitor:registration_form error_handling="inline" return='conta'}

                Email*: <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" />
                {error:email}

                Password*: <input id="password" name="membro_senha" type="password" value="" />
                {error:password}

                Confirm password*: <input id="password_confirm" name="membro_senha" type="password" value="" />

                Member firstname: <input id="mbr_membro_nome" name="mbr_membro_nome" type="text" value="" />
                {error:mbr_membro_nome}

                Member lastname: <input id="mbr_membro_sobrenome" name="mbr_membro_sobrenome" type="text" value="" />
                {error:mbr_membro_sobrenome}

                Gender (radiobuttons): {options:membro_sexo} <input id="membro_sexo" name="membro_sexo" type="radio" value="{option_value}" />{option_value} {/options:membro_sexo}

                Birthday (datepicker): <input id="membro_aniversario" maxlength="23" name="membro_aniversario" size="25" type="date" value="" />

                <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Register" />

    {/exp:visitor:registration_form}
```

[image: registration form]

But there is a problem with the **update form tag**, **nothings is displayed**, **a blank page** is displayed with absolutely no code, it seems EE doesn't recognise this tag:

```
{exp:visitor:update_form return='account/update_profile/success'}
        Member firstname: <input id="member_firstname" name="member_firstname" type="text" value="" />
        Member lastname: <input id="member_lastname" name="member_lastname" type="text" value="" />
        Gender (radiobuttons): {options:member_gender} <input id="member_gender" name="member_gender" type="radio" value="{option_value}" />{option_value} {/options:member_gender}
        Birthday (datepicker): <input id="member_birthday" maxlength="23" name="member_birthday" size="25" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Update profile" />
{/exp:visitor:update_form}
```

Did-someone has already encountered this problem?
I tried under PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0, 7.1, the problem still the same. I tested on Wamp 3.0.9 on Windows 10, and on and on a physical Apache server. On local with wamp and in the Apache server, the exp:visitor:update_form  doesn't work at all. I tried with EE 3.5.10 and EE 3.5.7.

What could be the problem ??? My Visitor 3.0.1 installation is ok.

If Someone encountered the same problem, I will relate it to DevDemon.

Comment: Are you logged in as a member on the browser you're testing update_form on?

Comment: Yes i'm logged as a member on the browser  when I'm testing update_form on. Even on a fresh install on a Apache server, with only Visitor as addon. The installation is ok. Betweeen exp:visitor:update_form command, nothing is displayed, on the html.. Logged as Admin this problem appears, so I will try to discover if there is a relation with member authorisations, or template access.

Comment: Hi Romans, thanks to your comment I immediately thought that always i was logged as admin, and never as a member. So the problem is solved, when I logged as admin update form tag is not processed, logged as member is proccessed. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the Romans-8---31-39 comment's, I discovered when i am logged as admin, exp:visitor:update_form is not processed, logged as member it is processed, so the the problem is solved!